# Discover WCF Service by link

Tags: web-services, wcf, webservice-discovery

I want to find a WCF service using it's address.
I wrote the following code:

```
var uri = "http://bla-blabla.svc"
var obj = new DiscoveryClient(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
        var findCriteria = new FindCriteria();
        findCriteria.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        findCriteria.Scopes.Add(new Uri(uri));
        var findResponse = obj.Find(findCriteria);
```

But it doesn't find anything...
If I try to search using WCF test client using the link, it works...
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use WCF test client, you are not using the Discovery feature. It's a classic call to the wsdl/metadata of the service.

Your target Service should be discoverable, by adding something in the host or in the config.

**Code**

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(...); 
host.AddServiceEndpoint(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
ServiceDiscoveryBehavior discovery = new ServiceDiscoveryBehavior();
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(discovery);
host.Open();
```

**Config**

```
<services>
       <service name = "MyService">
          <endpoint 
             kind = "udpDiscoveryEndpoint"
          />
          ...
       </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
       <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior>
             <serviceDiscovery/>
          </behavior>
       </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

At first, also remove the scope in the find criteria.